# Replacing three parts string in FME?

Tags: fme-form, regular-expression

How to replace three parts string with  (like John Doe Street) to form where first word has only one letter like (J. Doe Street)?

I am using FME (StringReplacer) so RegExp should be fine method for this case.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure that there's a way to do this with RegExp, but I would just use an AttributeSplitter, maybe a ListElementCounter and Tester to make sure it's 3 words, then a SubstringExtractor to get the first letter from the first element of the list, and finally a StringConcatenator to rebuild the output.